# How to sum by category in Google Sheets and manipulate the result?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this format:

```
A       B    C       D  
invoice date product amount
         D1   P1      10 
         D1   P2      100
         D1   P1      10
I1       D1   P1      10
```

I want to calculate the sum of non-invoiced products by product. I'm almost there with this:

```
=query($A$2:$D;"select C, sum(D) where A is null group by C")

   sum 
    
P1 20
P2 100
```

But I actually want to split this result (ignoring the "sum" header) and put it into two non-adjacent columns E and G:

```
       E   F   G  
row1  P1      20
ro22  P2      100
```

I guess I could write two separate array queries, one for E1 and another for G1, but I'm still not sure how to extract pieces of the QUERY result (and there might be a simpler approach than using QUERY).

[Live example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17oTLatoRWvv7SFKI5EEJq7hOaobYpdK4RmDS70Tbi4Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is there something in column F that you don't want to over-write?

Comment: it'd be easier to help if you shared a real sample. Here's a simple tool i built to share an "anonymous" sheet for that purpose if you'd like.
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, I'd rather not overwrite column F

Comment: @MattKing Sure, here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17oTLatoRWvv7SFKI5EEJq7hOaobYpdK4RmDS70Tbi4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ignoring columns in a formula is not possible. You need to create 2 QUERY functions.

**Try these formulas:**

For cell **E8**: `=QUERY(QUERY(A2:D5, "SELECT C, SUM(D) where A is null group by C label SUM(D) ''"), "SELECT Col1")`

For cell **G8**: `=QUERY(QUERY(A2:D5, "SELECT C, SUM(D) where A is null group by C label SUM(D) ''"), "SELECT Col2")`

Example:

[image]

[image]

### Reference:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)